# FPDF error: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF

Tags: php, drupal, fpdf

I am using the [fpdf](http://www.fpdf.org/) library for my project, and I'm using this to extend one of the drupal module. These lines

```
$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
$pdf->Cell(40,10,'Hello World!');
$pdf->Output();
```

give me an error: ***FPDF error: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF***

I tried creating this in a separate file outside the drupal area name test.php and when viewed it worked. Anyone here know why this don't work? Or anyone here can point me a right pdf library which I can use in drupal to view HTML to PDF format.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

For fpdf to work properly, there cannot be *any* output at all beside what fpdf generates. For example, this will work:

```
<?php
$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
$pdf->Cell(40,10,'Hello World!');
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

While this will not (note the leading space before the opening `<?` tag)

```
 <?php
$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
$pdf->Cell(40,10,'Hello World!');
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

Also, this will not work either (the `echo` will break it):

```
<?php
echo "About to create pdf";
$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
$pdf->Cell(40,10,'Hello World!');
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

I'm not sure about the drupal side of things, but I know that absolutely zero non-fpdf output is a requirement for fpdf to work.

Comment: oww ok, because i just inserted the code inside .tpl files. It has blocks of codes that uses echo/print, or html tags and javascript syntax.

Comment: btw - i don't use short tags in php. used this <?php ?>

Comment: Yep. that's your problem. Using `echo` will also break fpdf (I'll edit my answer to show that). The short tags vs. long tags shouldn't make a difference, but you'll have to make sure that there is not even a single character outside of your php tags.

Comment: @GordonBailey What would be approach in using fpdf in PHP MVC frameworks, for instance in phalconphp, but conceptual answer for MVC is very welcome

Comment: REMOVE the closing "?>" at the end of each PHP file, particularly any PHP file that might be "included" in the code. The very existence of the "?>" means there might be a "\r\n" EOL afterwards, depending on your editor, and that "\r\n" will be sent in the output Response and contaminate your PDF.

Comment: Thank you @gordeon i have same problem is happened in mpdf but localhost give pdf output but server give not output then i remove the white space before the "<?php " tag and my problem is resolved.

Comment: `echo` was a problem in my case!  Thank you

Answer (score 42):

add `ob_start ();` at the top and at the end add `ob_end_flush();`

```
<?php
    ob_start();
    require('fpdf.php');
    $pdf = new FPDF();
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
    $pdf->Cell(40,10,'Hello World!');
    $pdf->Output();
    ob_end_flush(); 
?>
```

Comment: This is the answer which solved my problem great work

Comment: This is the solution of error FPDF error: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF.

Answer (score 26):

give me an error as below:
`FPDF error: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF`

to over come this error:
go to `fpdf.php` in that,goto line number 996

```
function Output($name='', $dest='')
```

after that make changes like this:

```
function Output($name='', $dest='') {   
    ob_clean();     //Output PDF to so
```

Comment: I up-checked this answer because it works, particularly in cases where you have spaces or newlines outside of your <?php ?> tags, and can not find them all. It might be safer to call "ob_clean" from the calling function, instead of inside the "Output" function. Be warned, that it will also hide any legitimate error messages that might actually be causing the problem. If you fix the errors, which you ought to do anyway, that might solve your problem without resorting to "hacks" like this.

Comment: I used that but it shows me -
Notice: ob_clean(): failed to delete buffer. No buffer to delete in /var/www/html/-------/fpdf.php on line 981

Comment: This is working  perfeclty for me. upvote from my side.

Comment: I picked up the error noted by the OP after moving files to a new server. No changes, just updating from Windows Server 2012 to 2016. Adding ob_clean(); solved the problem.

Comment: Worked flawlessly for me. I was having this issue when trying to compare two strings.

Comment: I'm using this library: https://github.com/myokyawhtun/PDFMerger and this worked for me. Instead, I modified `/tcpdf/tcpdf.php`

Answer (score 5):

Try to save the file without the option:  "BOM comment", i.e. in Adobe Dreamweaver, you Save File As..., **uncheck** the box below the filename that says, "*Include Unicode signature(BOM)*".

On Notepad++ you should select the menu: **Encoding**, "*Encode in UTF-8 without BOM*".

And make it default for other files you create, it will spare you a lot of headaches in future.

Answer (score 3):

Hi do you have a session header on the top of your page.
or any includes
If you have then try to add this codes on top pf your page it should works fine.

```
<?

while (ob_get_level())
ob_end_clean();
header("Content-Encoding: None", true);

?>
```

cheers :-)

Answer (score 3):

In my case i had set:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
```

When i made the request to generate the report, some warnings were displayed in the browser (like the usage of deprecated functions).
Turning `off` the `display_errors` option, the report was generated successfully.

Answer (score 2):

The FPDF Error Message will point you to the PHP Line that is sending some content.

If you get no hint what File & Line send some content you probably have an encoding mismatch in your include / require Files.

For me

- `fpdf.php` was ANSI-encoded,
- my `pdf-generator.php` was UTF-8-encoded and
- my database-connect-inlude was UTF-8-encoded *(this UTF-8-encoding did raise the FPDF error. I had to switch it back to ANSI)*

Answer (score 2):

if you're code outputs notices/warnings before the PDF generation, try turning them off. `error_reporting(0)`. Then work on the warnings there-after

Comment: This should be posted as a comment.

Answer (score 2):

Add to the beginning of the script

```
ob_start();
require ('fpdf.php');
```

and at the end, after `output()`

```
ob_end_flush();
```

It worked for me! =)

Comment: this error showing today. its working from last 3 year and today not work

Comment: This made the trick, but ensure you don't have divs or other html stuff (even blank spaces), otherwise will silently fail.

Answer (score 2):

Even a single space in the included php files causes that warning. There shouldn't be any output in any way.

Answer (score 1):

First step
check the permissions on the folders
second step
put this

```
ob_start();
```

before the line

```
$pdf->Output();
```

Answer (score 1):

I used the following and it worked for me

```
require_once ('pdf/fpdf.php');

$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
$pdf->Cell(40,10,'Hello World!');
$pdf->Output(F,'/var/www/html/PATH/filename.pdf');
ob_end_flush();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the library

> require ('fpdf.php');

```
<?php
require('fpdf.php');

$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
$pdf->Cell(40,10,'¡Hola, Mundo!');
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

http://www.fpdf.org/

http://www.fpdf.org/es/tutorial/tuto1.htm

Answer (score 0):

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'FPDF error: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file (output started at /home/asri123/public_html/bill/invoice/invoice.php:743)' in /home/asri123/public_html/bill/invoice/fpdf.php:271 Stack trace: #0 /home/asri123/public_html/bill/invoice/fpdf.php(1052): FPDF->Error('Some data has a...') #1 /home/asri123/public_html/bill/invoice/fpdf.php(1012): FPDF->_checkoutput() #2 /home/asri123/public_html/bill/invoice/mirasbill.php(262): FPDF->Output('MSFS/2018-19/76...', 'D') #3 {main} thrown in /home/asri123/public_html/bill/invoice/fpdf.php on line 271

Comment: its working from last 3 year but today its stop on all sites please help me

Answer (score 0):

Another answer that nobody else has posted here... **Double-check the encoding of your PHP file** and make sure that it's not something other than UTF-8. The wrong code editor (or FTP upload?) can mess with the file's encoding in which case none of the other fixes mentioned in this thread will help.