# save HTML page to PDF in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, pdf, tcpdf

I need to convert url to pdf

I tried to use tcpdf but i get errors like:
Notice: Undefined offset: 4 in /opt/lampp/htdocs/IBI/tcpdf/tcpdf.php on line 17218
TCPDF ERROR: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file

I think that the problem is that the page have html and js and CSS

this is the code and the url that tried :

```
// Include the main TCPDF library (search for installation path).
require_once('tcpdf_include.php');

// create new PDF document
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

// set document information
$pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
$pdf->SetAuthor('Nicola Asuni');
$pdf->SetTitle('TCPDF Example 006');
$pdf->SetSubject('TCPDF Tutorial');
$pdf->SetKeywords('TCPDF, PDF, example, test, guide');

// set default header data
$pdf->SetHeaderData(PDF_HEADER_LOGO, PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, PDF_HEADER_TITLE.' 006', PDF_HEADER_STRING);

// set header and footer fonts
$pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
$pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));

// set default monospaced font
$pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);

// set margins
$pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
$pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
$pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);

// set auto page breaks
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);

// set image scale factor
$pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);

// set some language-dependent strings (optional)
if (@file_exists(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php')) {
    require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php');
    $pdf->setLanguageArray($l);
}

// ---------------------------------------------------------

// set font
$pdf->SetFont('dejavusans', '', 10);

// add a page
$pdf->AddPage();
// test some inline CSS
$html = file_get_contents("http://dvns.me/mahmoud/IBI/");
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');

//Close and output PDF document
$pdf->Output(time().'.pdf', 'I');

//============================================================+
// END OF FILE
//============================================================+
```

Comment: Can you check if your headers were already sent ? [reference `headers_sent`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.headers-sent.php)

Comment: @huggilou Where to check ? in the first of the code or in the end ?

Comment: Before `$pdt->Output()`function

Comment: @huggilou i tried to add echo headers_sent(); before the output ($pdf->Output(time().'.pdf', 'I');) and print true, that's meaning that the header is sent

Comment: Maybe you have a blank / space before the opening PHP tag "<?php"? Or there are blanks after the end tag in included files (what I do not believe, because it looks like you include only tcpdf files... but better double check).

Comment: The problem is here: $html = file_get_contents("http://dvns.me/mahmoud/IBI/");  because if i change it to $html = "<h1>HELLO WORLD</h1>"; it's work.

Comment: I am sorry, but I think, you will never get that page near (if even a little bit) correctly as a PDF with TCPDF! Too much not well formatted HTML and  Javascript...

Answer (score 0):

Try to insert `ob_clean()` before `require()` like

```
ob_clean()
// set document information
$pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
```

See the [reference here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-clean.php) and [related issue here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475686/fpdf-error-some-data-has-already-been-output-cant-send-pdf).

Answer (score 0):

I had achieved similar thing using the following library [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF)

In view define the table you wish to print using ID for ex:

```
<table id="printTable" class='table table-striped' border="0">
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to hide notice message with the following code :

```
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);
```

This code is to insert at the beginning of the script

Comment: i get this: 
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /opt/lampp/htdocs/IBI/tcpdf/tcpdf.php on line 19515

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /opt/lampp/htdocs/IBI/tcpdf/tcpdf.php on line 19515

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /opt/lampp/htdocs/IBI/tcpdf/tcpdf.php on line 19515

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /opt/lampp/htdocs/IBI/tcpdf/tcpdf.php on line 19515
TCPDF ERROR: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file

Comment: It seem that your html is not valid to output in the pdf file. Try to replace your `$html`var with a simpler example like `<html><body>Hello world</body></html>`

Comment: i tried before and it is working, i know that the problem is from the html outpou, but how can i fix it ? thanks

Comment: @huggilou please, var_dump the variable over which the foreach loops.

Comment: I take a look to your page you want to convert to PDF. The problem is that you have some javascript script which will not be executed with `file_get_contents` function... You should use a PDF conversion on client side to keep graphs and etc

Comment: I tried to add ob_end_clean();before the output, now i get results, but i see javascript code and the data but without design

Comment: @huggilou "You should use a PDF conversion on client side to keep graphs and etc" How can i make this thing ? are you have an example ?