# Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'FPDF error: Some data has already been output

Tags: php, wordpress, pdf, pdf-generation

I am trying to create a pdf file when a form is submitted in wordpress.
I am using FDPF and the code is

```
    <?php 
    /* Template Name: FORM TEST */ 

    get_header(); 
    /*** USE THE NEW HEADER FUNCTION **/
    WpkPageHelper::zn_get_subheader();

    if(isset($_POST['confirm'])){ 
        $fullname = $_POST['fullname'];
        $fathername = $_POST['fathername'];
        $dob = $_POST['dob'];
        $wpdb->insert( 
            'tck_customer', 
            array( 
                'name' => $fullname, 
                'fname' => $fathername 
            ), 
            array( 
                '%s', 
                '%s' 
            ) 
        );
?>
<?php
ob_start();
require(STYLESHEETPATH.'/fpdf/fpdf.php');
$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
$pdf->Cell(40,10,'Hello World!');
ob_clean();
flush();
$pdf->Output();
ob_end_flush(); 
?>
<form>
     FORM STUFFS
</form>
```

But this give me the errors when I submit the code.
Errors :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'FPDF error: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file (output started at /home4/q0i4l0g2/public_html/tck/wp-content/themes/kallyas/header.php:2)' in /home4/q0i4l0g2/public_html/tck/wp-content/themes/kallyas-child/fpdf/fpdf.php:271 Stack trace: #0 /home4/q0i4l0g2/public_html/tck/wp-content/themes/kallyas-child/fpdf/fpdf.php(1053): FPDF->Error('Some data has a...') #1 /home4/q0i4l0g2/public_html/tck/wp-content/themes/kallyas-child/fpdf/fpdf.php(1000): FPDF->_checkoutput() #2 /home4/q0i4l0g2/public_html/tck/wp-content/themes/kallyas-child/form-test.php(33): FPDF->Output() #3 /home4/q0i4l0g2/public_html/tck/wp-includes/template-loader.php(89): include('/home4/q0i4l0g2...') #4 /home4/q0i4l0g2/public_html/tck/wp-blog-header.php(16): require_once('/home4/q0i4l0g2...') #5 /home4/q0i4l0g2/public_html/tck/index.php(17): require('/home4/q0i4l0g2...') #6 {main} thrown in /home4/q0i4l0g2/public_html/tck/wp-content/themes/kallyas-child/fpdf/fpdf.php on line 271
```

how can I solve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FPDF error: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475686/fpdf-error-some-data-has-already-been-output-cant-send-pdf)

Comment: First of all, remove what you've added to fpdf.php file. Second, before calling the "output" method, call `ob_clean();` and `flush();`, and it should work just fine.

Comment: Remove unnecessary php tags. Keep it in single PHP tag.  Remove Space from start of the files

Comment: @DivyeshSavaliya all the the solution suggested in that question I applied. still the result is same

Comment: @Eihwaz could you please check my updated code.? is that waht you mentions?

Comment: @MangeshSatheIND Now there are two `php` tags. Have a look at first comment. as per that accepted answer it will not work if the is some extra code lines inside the `fpdf` code php wrapper

Comment: I would try to comment out `//$pdf->Output();` so the PDF is not rendered. I am guessing that will output some error / warnings. If it does, fix them, and then try to output again the pdf.