# wordpress fpdf - Uncaught exception

Tags: php, wordpress, pdf

I am trying to generate a pdf in my wordpress plugin and for this I am using FPDF library. I am getting the following error `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'FPDF error: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file`

Here I am trying to output the pdf using a wordpress shortcode mechanism in a page. I also tried all the possible soluions in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475686/fpdf-error-some-data-has-already-been-output-cant-send-pdf) but nothing worked for me. Anyone faced this issue in wordpress before?

Comment: Sounds like you've sent data before FPDF has had a chance to send headers. Do you use source control? Can you compare changes since adding FPDF and look for any leading whitespace before `<?php` tags or any errant `echo`'s or `print`'s?

Comment: you could be correct because my wordpress header loads before fpdf code. But I am not sure how to ignore header for one page in wordpress

Comment: I'm not sure how much you're relying on WP loading for the data you're putting in the PDF, but the cleanest approach would be to create a stand alone file that does the FPDF work without running any of WP.

Comment: Now I have created a separate file and fpdf is loading perfectly, but I have to bring some wordpress user data into this individual file, any idea how to do that?