# FPDF error: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file

Tags: php, fpdf, watermark, fpdi

I have to add a watermark to my existing pdf file.
I use fpdf and fpdi libraries.

My code is:

```
<?php
ob_start();
require('fpdf/fpdf.php');
require 'fpdi/fpdi.php';
$pdf = new FPDI();
$pdf->setSourceFile("Rabochaya_tetrad.pdf");
$tplIdx = $pdf->importPage(1, '/MediaBox');
$pdf->addPage();
$pdf->useTemplate($tplIdx, 0, 0, 0, 0, true); 
$pdf->SetFont('Arial');
$pdf->SetTextColor(0, 0, 0);
$pdf->SetXY(58, 45);
$your_dynamic_content="file watermark";
$pdf->Write(0,$your_dynamic_content);
$pdf->Output();
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

When I try to perform it, I get an error:

> FPDF error: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file

I tried all advices from [FPDF error: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475686/fpdf-error-some-data-has-already-been-output-cant-send-pdf), but it didn't help me.

Do you have any ideas about these issues?

Comment: Have you resolved the issue?

Answer (score 1):

You have to move the line `ob_start();` before the line `$pdf->Output()`.

The error is thrown because one (or more) function prints something and your PDF file is corrupted when displayed.

Answer (score 0):

require('fpdf/fpdf.php');

should be like this

require 'fpdf/fpdf.php';

refer to http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php