# get data from pdf string and display

Tags: php, jquery, pdf

I'm creating a pdf from formdata using fpdf (http://www.fpdf.org/).

Using Jquery I'm able to send the data to the pdf-creating script, and make the pdf appear in browser.

Now I'm trying to return the pdf-data to the formpage using fpdf's option to get the pdf as a string and echoing it.

```
$pdf_file_contents = $pdf->Output("","S");
echo $pdf_file_contents
```

My question now is

How do I use this data to preview the pdf under the form?
Do I need to use an pdf-viewer or can I use an `<iframe>` and am I doing this the correct way by returning the variable in an echo?

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two options:

- Embed a PDF viewer and handle that call in JS. (Wait for the response from PHP and display the outputted file inline)
- Trigger a redirect or load an iframe which displays `$pdf->Output($filename,"F")` from a temp file.

The result of `$pdf->Output()` is displayed using the browser's built-in viewer. If there is any output above that in the page FPDF will return an error to say `FPDF error: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF.`

[FPDF error: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475686/fpdf-error-some-data-has-already-been-output-cant-send-pdf#9475817)

There might be some other option I'm missing but those would be my first suggestions.