# Creating pdf using fpdf in PHP on 000webhost seen some error

Tags: php, fpdf

I have trying this code

```
<?php
require ("fpdf/fpdf.php");
$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
$pdf->Cell(40,10,'Hello World!');
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

But I see the below errors:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: FPDF error: Some data has already
>   been output, can't send PDF file (output started at
>   /storage/ssd1/896/5392896/public_html/admin/case_pdf.php:1) in
>   /storage/ssd1/896/5392896/public_html/admin/fpdf/fpdf.php:271 Stack
>   trace: #0
>   /storage/ssd1/896/5392896/public_html/admin/fpdf/fpdf.php(1052):
>   FPDF->Error('Some data has a...') #1
>   /storage/ssd1/896/5392896/public_html/admin/fpdf/fpdf.php(999):
>   FPDF->_checkoutput() #2
>   /storage/ssd1/896/5392896/public_html/admin/case_pdf.php(28):
>   FPDF->Output() #3 {main} thrown in
>   /storage/ssd1/896/5392896/public_html/admin/fpdf/fpdf.php on line 271

Comment: check this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475686/fpdf-error-some-data-has-already-been-output-cant-send-pdf?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this before generating PDF

```
ob_end_clean();
```