# FPDF error: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\movie\form.php:15)

Tags: php, forms, fpdf

I want to create a PDF from a form, but im stuck. It says
 "Some data has already been output" and I know it's the $name. But any
 idea how I can solve this problem?

```
  <?php
    ob_end_clean();
    if(!empty($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $name= $_POST['name'];
        $date = $_POST['date'];
        $movie = $_POST['movie'];
    }

        require_once ('fpdf/fpdf.php');
        $pdf = new FPDF();
        $pdf->AddPage();
        $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
        $pdf->Cell(40,10,$name);
        $pdf->Output();
        ob_end_flush(); 
    ?>
```

Comment: Could you please paste in the full error message as it appears on the screen?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FPDF error: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475686/fpdf-error-some-data-has-already-been-output-cant-send-pdf)

Comment: @Dharman Notice: Undefined variable: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\movie\form.php on line 15
FPDF error: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\movie\form.ph

Answer (score 0):

1. There can't be any text output to page. Because of undefined variable there is this text:

   > Notice: Undefined variable: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\movie\form.php on line 15
2. Because of that error text, there is problem with exporting PDF.

You have two options.

Option 1:
Just put your FPDF code into if clause. This way it will be defined.

```js
<?php
        ob_end_clean();
        if(!empty($_POST['submit'] && !empty(&_POST['name'])
        {
            $name= $_POST['name'];
            $date = $_POST['date'];
            $movie = $_POST['movie'];
        
            require_once ('fpdf/fpdf.php');
            $pdf = new FPDF();
            $pdf->AddPage();
            $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
            $pdf->Cell(40,10,$name);
            $pdf->Output();
            ob_end_flush(); 
        }
     ?>
```

Option 2:
Set value for $name, if not submited.

```js
  <?php
    ob_end_clean();
    if(!empty($_POST['submit'])
    {
        $name= $_POST['name'];
        $date = $_POST['date'];
        $movie = $_POST['movie'];
    } else {
        $name= '';
    }
        require_once ('fpdf/fpdf.php');
        $pdf = new FPDF();
        $pdf->AddPage();
        $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
        $pdf->Cell(40,10,$name);
        $pdf->Output();
        ob_end_flush(); 
 ?>
```

Comment: Yeah, i know that. But idk how i can solve this problem,sir