# Pass HTML with loops inside to a variable in php

Tags: php, html, web, tcpdf

In php, I want to create pdf with `tcpdf`. based on tutorials, I have to put html tags in a variable as string and then pass that variable to `tcpdf`. like this:

```
$html = "<div>Hello World</div>";
$pdf->writeHTMLCell(0, 0, '', '', $html, 0, 1, 0, true, '', true);
```

But in a real world application, I want to do some foreach inside my html and create html tags from database data.

```
<div><?php foreach ($myData as $key => $value) {echo $value}; ?></div>;
```

But in this way, I get an error:

```
Some data has already been output to browser, can't send PDF file
```

What I have to do? in fact I want tp put a large html with php loops inside that completes that html inside a variable, and the pass that variable to `tcpdf` whithout getting that error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are outputting data to the request body before you send the PDF.

This could be a space or newline before your `<?php` tag or perhaps an `echo` statement from previous debugging attempts.

Quick example, this is correct

```
<?php // code
```

and these aren't

```
 <?php // code
```

```
<?php // code
```

for a more detailed explanation see this answer 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9475817/9208510